# Wireless dropouts that only affect subset of devices

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

When watching videos streamed over WiFi from a NAS box (D-Link DNS-323) I am getting wireless dropouts. However they only appear to occur when I have left my laptop (Dell Inspiron 9300 running Windows XP SP3) running; the laptop is usually suspended if I'm not using it.

The dropouts have occurred when streaming to a Netgear EVA8000 streaming device, and also to a PS3. I'm using a Netgear DG834G as the wireless modem/router.

When a dropout occurs I go to the laptop and see that its wireless connection has also dropped out. The odd thing is that my wife's MacBook and my iPhone still maintain their connections.

What could be causing this behaviour, and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went back to an earlier version of the router's firmware, and used [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider) to select the best WiFi channel. Wireless connections are now back to rock-solid.